# Hi, I have a problem with the array with the data entry

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a problem with arrays, I would like to create a table by entering the students and
grades of each student in the following subjects.
But I have a problem when I go to print on the console, the rows and columns are not matched,
also I should find the highest and the lowest number.
And try to do the average. HERE IS AN IMAGE OF THE OUTPUT:
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMqEf.png)

```
    public static int voti1 = 0;
    public static int voti2;
    public static int voti3;
    public static int voti4;
    public static int somma = 0;
    public static int media;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] materie = { "Italiano", "Musica", "Geografia", "Biologia" };

    for (int i = 0; i < materie.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%34s", materie[i]);
    }

    String[] nomiAlunni = { "Derby Harringthon", "Gord Vendome", "Justin Vandervelde", "Tad 
     Smith" };
    for (int j = 0; j < nomiAlunni.length; j++) {
        System.out.print("\n" + nomiAlunni[j]);
    }

    String votiAlunno1[] = { "8", "4", "5", "6" };
    String votiAlunno2[] = { "3", "6", "9", "8" };
    String votiAlunno3[] = { "5", "9", "10", "7" };
    String votiAlunno4[] = { "10", "9", "8", "3" };

    for (int i = 0; i < votiAlunno1.length; i++) {
        voti1 = Integer.parseInt(votiAlunno1[i]);
        System.out.printf("%27s", votiAlunno1[i]);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < votiAlunno2.length; i++) {
        voti2 = Integer.parseInt(votiAlunno2[i]);
        System.out.print("\t\t" + votiAlunno2[i]);

    }

    voti1 = Integer.parseInt(votiAlunno1[0]);
    voti2 = Integer.parseInt(votiAlunno2[1]);
    voti3 = Integer.parseInt(votiAlunno3[2]);
    voti4 = Integer.parseInt(votiAlunno4[3]);

    /*
     * for(i = 1; i<votiAlunno2.length; i++) { for (int j = 1; j <
     * votiAlunno2[i].length(); j++) { System.out.printf("%30s", "\t" +
     * votiAlunno1[i]); }
     * 
     */

    for (int i = 0; i < votiAlunno1.length; i++) {
        voti1 = Integer.parseInt(votiAlunno1[i]);
        somma = somma + voti1;
        media = voti1 / somma;

    }

    System.out.println("La media dei voti è" + media);

    }

    }

    enter code here[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of what the expected output should be? It's a little hard to infer from your description of the problem. One thing to keep in mind is that printing to the console is done sequentially. So if you want the contents of `votiAlunno1[]` to appear next to  the name "Derby Harringthon", then you should print "Derby Harringthon", followed by the contents of `votiAlunno1[]` before you print the `\n` character.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are printing a table.

```java
String[] nomiAlunni = { "Derby Harringthon", "Gord Vendome", "Justin Vandervelde", "Tad 
     Smith" };
    for (int j = 0; j < nomiAlunni.length; j++) {
        System.out.print("\n" + nomiAlunni[j]);
    }
```

You print the `nomiAlunni` spanning through lines already. Note that `print` goes sequentially; once the stream is flushed, you cannot go back to the previous lines. Instead, try to do something like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < nomiAlunni.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%27s", nomiAlunni[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < votiAlunno[i].length; j++) 
        System.out.printf("\t%s", votiAlunno[i][j]);
}
```

Try to implement `noniAlunni` as a multidimensional array to save lines.  You need not `parseInt` for printing; `toString()` of any object is called when printing. Try to be consistent with `\t`: java is intelligent enough
to optimize your output.

Comment: because when I enter inside the for loop the system out printf and entering grades studentl[i][j] gives me error, can it be that I have to create a two-dimensional array?

Comment: It is more suitable to use a two-dimensional array here. You have to change your code to have it works. [Multidimensional arrays in java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-in-java/)